# Can't update view after loading image from storage

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm binding an image from windows storage to an `Image` control in my View
here is some code: (`Images` is an `ObservableCollection`)

```
 // Loading images from storage
        foreach (var imagesVM in Images)
        {
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            var tmp = await ImageHelpers.LoadImageFromStorageAsync(
                imagesVM.name);
            if (tmp != null)
            {
                img.SetSource(tmp);
                imagesVM.Logo = img;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => imagesVM.Logo);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Images);
            }
        }
```

My `LoadImageFromStorageAsync` method return null if image is not found.

My problem is that my View isn't updating when images are loaded, if I'm drag&droping an element, the element update and the image is shown, here's my binding:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Logo, Mode=TwoWay}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

Binding works well, since it shows when updating (also when I go back then re-open this page)

More strange, my images are sometimes displayed ...

Any guess? I suppose it's something with `RaisePropertyChanged`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably this: `RaisePropertyChanged(() => imagesVM.Logo);`

Try changing your `imagesVM` type to raise its own property changed notification when `Logo` is set.

Comment: Oh my... I totally forgot to implement that.. Thanks a lot =D